# Filling Data according to a Template file(DOTX) using Aspose .NET

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

I have a MS word template file (DOTX). It has Header, Footer and Body. Inside body, there are some labels like

Header

**Emp ID:**

**Emp Name:**

Footer

Now I need to fill up those labels with data using Aspose Words .Net

My task is to generate the doc files for multiple Employees with help of this template.

I have seen many solutions but couldn't understand how to fetch those labels and fill them up . Should the template must contain bookmarks or fields? I have tried `"doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties"` and `"doc.CustomDocumentProperties"`, but these are not giving those required labels.

So Can anyone guide me or help me doing this task.

Comment: the easiest would be to work with `docx` and drop some tokens in the field where you wanted. then use [aspose find and replace](https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/find-and-replace/) feature. but if you have to work with `dotx`, is your "field" actually a proper field? if yes, you can use [mail merge thing](https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/mail-merge-and-reporting/). its all depends on the file you want to play with - how its constructed.

Comment: also, if you dont dealing with pdf, dont pollute [tag:aspose.pdf] tag. please use relevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can use either [Mail Merge](https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/mail-merge-and-reporting/) or [LINQ Reporting Engine](https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/linq-reporting-engine/).
In case of using Mail Merge, you should insert [merge fields](https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/mail-merge-template/) where values must be  inserted. Your template will look like the following:
[image]
Then you can use the following simple code to fill your document with data:

```cs
Document doc = new Document(@"C:\Temp\in.docx");
string[] fieldNames = new string[] { "EmpID", "EmpName" };
string[] fieldValues = new string[] { "007", "James Bond" };
doc.MailMerge.Execute(fieldNames, fieldValues);
doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.docx");
```

In case of using LINQ Reporting Engine, instead of MS Word merge fields, you should use [specials syntax](https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/template-syntax/). The template should look like this:
[image]
And the following code to fill the template with data:

```cs
// In LINQ Reporting Engine you can use variouse data sources,
// For demonstraction purposes use JSON.
string json = "{ \"EmpID\" : \"007\", \"EmpName\" : \"James Bond\" }";
Document doc = new Document(@"C:\Temp\in.docx");
ReportingEngine engine = new ReportingEngine();
JsonDataSource dataSource = new JsonDataSource(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)));
engine.BuildReport(doc, dataSource);
doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.docx");
```

As alternative not traditional solutions you can also use text placeholders and find/replace feature to replace them with real data or bookmarks as a placeholder for your data.

Comment: Hey @alexey thanks man, it worked and I have used the mail merge thing.